# MYSQL with result depending on other result? CASE WHEN?

Tags: mysql

I hope someone can help me here with the following problem.

I have a database with two prices. Firstly the normal price and the discounted price.
If the price is over '100' shipping is free '0' otherwise the value is 10.

The discounted price does not always have a value. Therefore I need to figure out first if there is only a normal price or also a discounted price and depending on the result I need to determine if shipping is '10' or '0'.

I have tried with tow case when statements but the code is not valid:

```
CASE WHEN D.product_override_price > 0.01 then round (D.product_override_price,2) else round (D.product_price * J.vat) when < 100 then 10.00 else 0.00 END as Shipping_Cost
```

I would be very glad to get some help or advice how to solv this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two CASE statements:

```
CASE
  WHEN (
    CASE
      WHEN D.product_override_price > 0.01
        THEN round (D.product_override_price,2)
      ELSE round (D.product_price * J.vat)
    END) < 100
  THEN 10.00
  ELSE 0.00
END as Shipping_Cost
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a small mistake you have missed left operand in `when`.

```
CASE WHEN D.product_override_price > 0.01 then round (D.product_override_price,2) else round (D.product_price * J.vat) when < 100 then 10.00 else 0.00 END as Shipping_Cost
```

Change it to:

**Edit:**

```
CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN D.product_override_price > 0.01 then round (D.product_override_price,2) else round (D.product_price * J.vat) END) < 100 then 10.00 else 0.00 END as Shipping_Cost
```

Hope it will work.